# Read the data from the file and store it in two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

hello I am having trouble with trying to read a file and take the two columns of the file and put them respectively in their own arrays. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file to be read");
    String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
    Scanner chirping = null;//user input for file name
    boolean fileValue = false; //this makes the value false until the correct file name is inputed
    while(!fileValue) {
        try {
            FileReader dates = new FileReader(fileName); // connects to the user inputted file
            chirping = new Scanner(dates); //scans the file
            fileValue = true; //turns file value to true which takes us out of the while loop

            }//end try
        catch(IOException e)  {
            System.out.println("File Not Found, Please Try Again: ");
            fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
        }//end catch
}// end while
    double[] dataSet = new double[30];
    double[] chirpFreq = new double[30];
    double[] temp = new double[30];
    //double[] temp = new double[chirping.nextInt()];
        for(int i = 0; chirping.hasNextDouble(); i++) {
                dataSet[i] = chirping.nextDouble();
        }

        for(int j = 0; j <= dataSet.length; j++) {
            if(j%2 == 0) {
                chirpFreq[j] = dataSet[j];
            }
            else {
                temp[j] = dataSet[j];
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= chirpFreq.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(chirpFreq[i]+ " ");
        }
        chirping.close();
}
```

//These are the values i am trying to sort into two separate arrays

`20     88.6
16      71.6
19.8    93.3
18.4    84.3
17.1    80.6
15.5    75.2
14.7    69.7
17.1    82
15.4    69.4
16.2    83.3
15      79.6
17.2    82.6
16      80.6
17      83.5
14.4    76.3`

Comment: Exactly what problem are you having?

Comment: `j <= dataSet.length;` is going to give you an Array Out Of Bounds Exception

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes thats the error is giving me how do i get around this or what exaclty am i doing wrong?

Comment: array indexes start at `0` and range up to `length - 1`, so `for (int j = 0; j < dataSet.length; j++) {..}`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Okay i got that to work thanks! I got my values assigned to the right arrays, the only issue is that for the indexs that remain that I didnt fill they default to zero.

Comment: @DevilsHnd My problem is getting the the two columns into two separate individual arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I don't usually use `nextDouble()` to read files so i don't know what your problem is exactly, but you can refactor your code to this:

```java
double[] firstColumn = new double[30];
double[] secondColumn = new double[30];

String line = "";
int i = 0;

// keep reading until there is nothing to read
while( (line = chirping.nextLine()) != null ) {

    // this is a regex that splits the line into an array based on whitespace 
    // just use " " if your data is separated by space or "\t" if tab
    String[] columns = line.split("\\s+");

    firstColumn[i] = Double.parseDouble(columns[0]);
    secondColumn[i++] = Double.parseDouble(columns[1]);
}

chirping.close();
```

Comment: better syntax than my idea!

Comment: @Jeffrey I get an error when I do this. What does the "colums = line.split(\\s+);" do?

Comment: @cgrubick oh my bad it should be a string array, i edited my answer